# How can I search within listview

Tags: c#, listview

How can I search within (listview) displays data So when he finds the item is indicated by the blue color inside the (listview)

```
 private void butsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Class1.x);

      DataSet mydata = new DataSet();
      mydata.Clear();
      SqlDataAdapter db = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM okk WHERE username LIKE '%" + textBox4.Text + "%'", cn);
      db.Fill(mydata, "uspas");
      textBox4.DataBindings.Clear();
      textBox4.DataBindings.Add("text", mydata, "uspas.okk");
      listView1.SelectedItems.data....// I could not be completed because I do not know
 }
```

Comment: Don't use SQL Queries like this. This is very unsafe and bad practise. Use SQL commands instead http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/sql_in_csharp.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Look this example, this is the way you can add new elements to a ListView, what I see is that the action for button3 is to search and to add, so this must be your problem, if not what do you want to do.

```
private void LoadList()
{
    // Get the table from the data set
    DataTable dtable = _DataSet.Tables["Titles"];

    // Clear the ListView control
    listView1.Items.Clear();

    // Display items in the ListView control
    for (int i = 0; i < dtable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow drow = dtable.Rows[i];

        // Only row that have not been deleted
        if (drow.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
        {
            // Define the list items
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(drow["title"].ToString());
            lvi.SubItems.Add (drow["title_id"].ToString());
            lvi.SubItems.Add (drow["price"].ToString());
            lvi.SubItems.Add (drow["pubdate"].ToString());

            // Add the list items to the ListView
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to delete selected items, you would do like this:

```
foreach(System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem eachItem in
this.listView1.SelectedItems)
{

}
```

Comment: thanks>:) Do you have an example of using the applications and not asp ?

Comment: help me please in this problem... :(

Comment: I need more code and a more detailed description try to paste the code in pastebin.com

Comment: I've changed my answer, not quite sure about what you want to do